# How to correctly send SIGTSTP signal to a child process?

Tags: c, process, signals

I am writing a custom shell program for an assignment where I do fork() and exec(). What I want to do is handle the signal SIGTSPS so that it suspends the child process.

I am currently handling crtl z with

```
 void SIGTSTP_Handler(){

if (child != 0) {
    kill(child, SIGTSTP);
    }
}
```

and my parent process waitpid with

```
if (waitpid(child, &status, WUNTRACED |WCONTINUED ) == -1) {
        err(-1, "Failed to waitpid()");
    }
if(WIFSTOPPED(status))
{

    printf("child stop with code: %d\n", WIFSTOPPED(status));
}
```

when I press ctrl Z my process stop but it exit with code 1. which means error. I want to be able to suspend the child process and resume it if i pass it a CONT signal. How do i properly handthe ctrl Z so that it suspend the child process and if I input fg it will put the suspend process back into running?

```
sleep 10
PID 71740: I must be the parent!
^Z
71740child stop with code: 1
```

Comment: Download the source code for `strace` as it does similar things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your child process is stopped, not exited. If it had exited, WIFSTOPPED(status) would be 0 and WIFEXITED(status) would be nonzero.

To continue the process, when your `fg` command is executed, send the `SIGCONT` signal to the child:

`kill(child, SIGCONT)`

Comment: hmm when sending a child process the SIGSTSP, should i see it when I invoke jobs on the terminal? or if i did not yet implement a signal handler for fg, should it bring my suspended child into the fg?

Comment: Not sure I understand the first question -- aren't you implementing your own shell, presumably with its own `jobs` command?

Comment: As for the second question, you don't need to implement a signal handler for `SIGCONT`. The child process will automatically resume execution when it receives one.